# pytest if else check

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock, pytest-cov

I am trying to learn pytest and testing my knowledge on the below code.

**src.py**

```
def a(s):
    if s == 1:
        return True
    if s == 2:
        return False
    return 3

def abc(u):
    if u ==1:
        if a(u):
            return 1
    else:
        if a(u):
            return 2
        else:
            return 3
```

and this is my test file:

```
import pytest
import src


@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_data, expected", [(1,1), (2,2), (3,2)])
def test_abc(input_data, expected, mocker):
    s = mocker.patch('src.a', side_effect=[True, False])
    assert src.abc(input_data) == expected
    s.assert_called_once_with(input_data)

@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_data, expected", [(1,True), (2,False), (3,3)])
def test_a(input_data, expected,):
    assert src.a(input_data) == expected
```

Testing the code returns all passed, but the coverage reports that the line 16 is not being tested:

```
% pytest -v --cov=. . --cov-report term-missing
==================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /Users/tomhanks/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/bin/python3.10
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/tomhanks/projects/pytest
plugins: mock-3.7.0, cov-3.0.0
collected 6 items                                                                                                                                           

test_me.py::test_abc[1-1] PASSED                                                                                                                      [ 16%]
test_me.py::test_abc[2-2] PASSED                                                                                                                      [ 33%]
test_me.py::test_abc[3-2] PASSED                                                                                                                      [ 50%]
test_me.py::test_a[1-True] PASSED                                                                                                                     [ 66%]
test_me.py::test_a[2-False] PASSED                                                                                                                    [ 83%]
test_me.py::test_a[3-3] PASSED                                                                                                                        [100%]

---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.10.4-final-0 ----------
Name         Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------
src.py          13      1    92%   16
test_me.py      10      0   100%
------------------------------------------
TOTAL           23      1    96%


===================================================================== 6 passed in 0.07s =====================================================================
```

Can somebody please help me understand why the line 16 is not being tested?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is line 16?

Comment: The very last else statement which returns 3

Comment: I'm getting different results, 100% coverage with 5 tests pass and one failed, the `(2,2)` parameter should go to the missing line and result in test failure.

Comment: `a` can return `True`, `False` *or `3`* but you only define `side_effect=[True, False]`. Exhausting `side_effect` should also trigger `StopIteration` – since that doesn't happen, it looks like each test creates a new mock *and thus only provides the first `side_effect` value `True`*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - how do I fix this? Do I need to create a fixture? Can you please help me understand! Thank you very much!